# Questions about some American English vocabulary

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I was wondering if any **American** writers could give me some advice as to whether the following expressions/vocab are used and understood in the US:

(words in bold are the ones I'm asking about. Some words are also in inverted commas)

1. The **living room** of a house -- is this expression ok? Do you ever say "front room" or "sitting room"? If it's a massive house with a huge entertainment area, can you say "living area"?
2. I was **tickled** -- is this expression ok? It means happy.
3. "My **college mate** wants to hang out at my **digs**" - meaning my place, or college dorm. Would **digs** be used? Is **college mate** an ok expression for someone you go to college with?
4. In the real world, do people stop on the **shoulder** or the **hard shoulder** of a highway or is either fine?
5. Is **median strip** used for the partition between 2 lanes of a highway going in different directions?
6. "He **takes the piss out of** every banker he meets" -- meaning he **mocks** them. Is this used?
7. Can you say "I'm **pissed off** at him" (angry) or does it have to be: "I'm **pissed** at him."
8. "I called my parents' **landline** (fixed home phone)." Is **landline** ok?
9. "I tried on the jeans in the **changing room**." Is this ok or does it have to be **fitting room** or something else?
10. Is the word "**thingamajig**" used in American English?
11. "I can't walk on my **ropey** leg" -- meaning *damaged* or *injured* or tired. Can **ropey** be used?
12. Security guards are **surveilling** the place. This verb is showing up as misspelt but I see it sometimes. Is there another spelling or verb?

13.In the real world, do people in the US use **MPH** or **KPH** as the unit of speed when driving?

14. Is the expression "**Calm my jitters**" acceptable? (calm my nerves)
15. If you pull up to a mansion surrounded by a fence with very thick metal bars all around it, is the word "**fence**" appropriate or is there a better word. I think that gate would only be for a door in a fence or something?
16. Is the expression "**It cost a pretty penny**" ever used in the US?
17. Is the expression "**It took every ounce of strength**" used in the US?
18. Can the word "**skiff**" be used in the US for a sort of flat-bottomed row boat?

Thank you so much to anyone willing to give advice about these points. Though I appreciate any input, I think it would be most useful to hear from actual American writers to avoid possible confusion.

Many thanks!

Follow up questions:

Thanks to all those who gave their very useful opinions. I have a couple more questions for anyone willing to give advice:

1. What do you call the area (let's say on the 10th floor) in front of an elevator door? Is there a specific word like "the landing"?
2. When you enter a house (without a mud room), there is a space just past the front door which is not really a room, but it's like the entrance way/hallway between the front door and other rooms like the living room, study. Is this called a "hallway"? It's not a lobby, obviously as that would be for a hotel or something. Can it be the "entrance hall"?
3. If you are using WASP-y as an adjective, do you have to write it like "WASP-y" or "WASPy". I'm guessing "waspy" hasn't become a thing yet?

Thank you!

Comment: The ones that jump out at me as UK English are numbers 6, 11, and 18. We also rarely use "mate" to mean "friend," although it is used in the context of "spouse" and of "roommate" (someone who shares a flat, you might say). I've never heard the term "hard shoulder" for the shoulder of a road, but "soft shoulder" is used on warning signs when the shoulder is likely to give way under a car or truck. The others are all more or less common and familiar to a U.S. English speaker, I think. "Surveilling" is a bit odd, but not out of the question in the context you give. We'd say "mph" for #13.

Comment: Thank you so much Sven! I really appreciate you giving your opinion. If you don't mind me picking your brain, is there an alternative to "he takes the piss out of" that's informal (other than he "mocks" or "makes fun of")? Would a US speaker ever say "my dodgy leg" to mean damaged? Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of expressions equivalent to "takes the piss out," of varying degrees of vulgarity. "Teases" is common, as is "kids"; more colloquially, we have "busts [one's] chops"; and more vulgarly "breaks [one's] balls" (the last is _Goodfellas_ talk; I have rarely heard people use it in everyday conversation). I think U.S. English tends to go with "bad leg" for damaged leg, though more specifically someone might refer to a "trick knee" (one that locks up unpredictably). I've also heard or read the term "gamy leg" but I don't remember if that was from a U.S. English source or not.

Comment: I might add that "tickled" is probably a regionalism these days. I heard it a lot in Texas while growing up there, but rarely or never in Washington, D.C., New York City, or the San Francisco Bay Area, where I have lived as an adult. A fairly large house may well have both a "front room" and a "living room." "Sitting room" and "parlor" may still be used in parts of the U.S., but I don't think they are at all common in most places. And finally "digs" is a bit unusual; it may have some currency, but it's not a standard way to refer to one's dorm room, apartment, or home.

Comment: @SvenYargs I wouldn't agree with the OP that *tickled* meant *happy*, more *amused, and unable to stop laughing at something* - like, err, being tickled!

Comment: Thank you Sven! You made me laugh with your *Goodfellas* talk! I don't need any of that in my book. Thanks so much for your advice. I will be taking it on board!

Comment: @WS2: In regional U.S. English it means "delighted" or "very pleased": "We're just so tickled that you could come down here and pay us a visit!"

Comment: The way one names the rooms of a house is very much correlated by social class, pretension, being non-U, etc in Britain, also I should think in America too.

Comment: "You can sit here in the waiting room, or you can wait here in the sitting room."

Comment: @SvenYargs I just looked up *tickle* in the OED and there are a vast number of derivatives etc - *tickled pink*, *tickle the ivories* etc. It is a subject too large to go into with a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my (highly subjective) take on the Americanness of the 18 terms you asked about (compiled from my earlier comments with further additions):

1. A fairly large house may well have both a "front room" and a "living room." "Sitting room" and "parlor" may still be used in parts of the U.S., but I don't think they are at all common in most places. "Living area" implies the part of a house you actually use, as opposed to the part that is sealed off or inaccessible; for most people the whole house (aside from the garage and maybe the laundry room) qualifies as "living area."
2. "Tickled" is used in regional U.S. English it means "delighted" or "very pleased": "We're just so tickled that you could come down here and pay us a visit!" It is not very common in the metropolitan areas where I've lived in recent years (Washington, D.C., New York City, and the San Francisco Bay Area).
3. I would expect a typical U.S. version of "My college mate wants to hang out at my digs" to be something like "My friend from college wants to hang out at my place." "Digs" is certainly not unheard of here, but "mate" has a distinctly British Commonwealth sound to it.
4. I've never heard the term "hard shoulder" for the shoulder of a road, but "soft shoulder" is used on warning signs when the shoulder is likely to give way under a car or truck.
5. "Median strip" is indeed common in U.S. English for the physical divider (not just a double yellow line) separating traffic headed in opposite directions on a highway, freeway, or busy street.
6. "Takes the piss out" is known in the U.S. only as a UK import. We might say "busts [one's] chops" in a similar situation, or less colloquially "ridicules."
7. Both "pissed at" and "pissed off at" are commonly heard in the U.S. I think "pissed off at" was the earlier phrase.
8. I'm pretty sure that "landline" is the standard term for a fixed home phone in U.S. parlance.
9. I've certainly heard "changing room" an "fitting room" used, though "dressing room" is also common. "Changing room" is sometimes used to refer to a place for changing a baby's diapers, I think.
10. "Thingamajig" and "thingamabob" are still heard in the U.S. They sound a bit old-fashioned to me, but not ludicrously so.
11. We don't generally use "ropy or "dodgy" for a damaged or tired leg. I would expect to hear "bad leg" or "tired legs."
12. "Surveilling is okay, I guess, but "keeping [a person or place] under surveillance" is much more common.
13. In the U.S. we still refer to "mph" or "MPH," not having yet abandoned the British measurement system.
14. "Calm my jitters" is passable, though "calm my nerves" or simply "calm down" is much more common.
15. "Metal fence" to me implies a barred metal fence of the kind you describe. We would use "cyclone fence" for the kind of fence that consists of a series of hollow metal poles and a thick wire mesh stretched across them.
16. My grandmother always used to say "I'll bet that cost a pretty penny"—but she was from Canada, so I'm not sure how Canadian del Sur the expression is. It sounds natural to me, anyway.
17. Yes, we still sometimes say "It took every ounce of strength I had."
18. "Skiff" is a word I've seen in books for decades but rarely heard used. I would expect "flat-bottomed boat" to be the more common way of describing this watercraft in the United States.

Comment: @Josh61: Yep, you'll notice that there is not one link or citation to corroborate anything I said. I figured that if I was going to cover all 18 questions, I wasn't going to do a scholarly job of it.

Comment: Thank you so much Sven! I really, really appreciate your input and will apply it to my writing. I only expected opinions and certainly didn't expect to get any supporting material or links as they aren't needed. An opinion from an American English speaker is all I expected and is very useful. Thanks again.

Comment: On 18: I'm quite familiar with _skiff_, but I grew up in an east coast seafaring town. It might be somewhat regional. On 12: I agree with you. We'd probably use _watching_ rather than _surveilling_. As for _digs_ (No. 3), that sounds a little dated to me, a bit like _groovy_.

Comment: To have the jitters is pretty common. So, calm them does not seem strange. Thingamabob or jig, is also common. Though, there are a lot of thingies and whosits out there.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Living area**. This is a term of art in real estate, and refers to the finished, heated area of a house.  This should be a calculation that gives a meaningful number for comparison. Unfortunately, it's calculated differently by assessors, [real estate agents](http://www.myhomemontreal.com/files/Calculating%20living%20area1.pdf), and developers.  You wouldn't use it to describe a particular room.
2. **tickled**.  *[Tickled pink](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tickled+pink)* is to be happy and pleased.  *Tickled* is to be happy and amused.
3. **mate**, **digs**.  Then Ngram viewer finds that *college mate* peaked in popularity at the turn of the last century.  *Digs* referring to in-college living arrangements is more British than American.  That said, everyone would understand your sentence.
4. **Ropey**.  No, *Partridge* has the word with various meanings from the 1940s and 1950s but "injured" isn't one of them.  *Dodgy* means perilous ("a dodgy situation") or shady ("a dodgy business arrangement.")  A damaged leg is a *[bum leg](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bum)*.
5. **Kilometers per hour.**  No one in the US will have the vaguest idea of what you're talking about.

(All of this for vernacular American English.)

Comment: Thank you - very useful. There is a question I forgot: In the US, do people say "we made chit chat"? or "we chit chat about something"?

Comment: @MoniqueH We chit chat or make small talk.

Comment: Good point about "bum leg"—I forgot that one. I also like your "sit or wait" comment.

Comment: ***MPH***: This is a measurement of speed typically used in non-metric countries for transport such as the USA. The United Kingdom also uses this on the roads although officially the metric system has been adopted. Road speed limits are given in miles per hour which is abbreviated as mph or mi/h.http://www.metric-conversions.org/speed/miles-per-hour-to-kilometers-per-hour.htm

Comment: @SvenYargs I can't take the credit, which belongs to *The Firesign Theater*.

Comment: As for Kilometer PH, would Americans  really haven't the faintest idea of  what that refers to? It is not used, but kilometer is not a mysterious word, I guess.

Comment: @Josh61Trust me.  *Kilometer* is not only mysterious, it's suspect.  Jesus used miles per hour, and that's good enough for us.

Comment: deadrat: If you gave me your speed in KPH, this American _would_ know what you were talking about – but I'd have no idea if you were speeding or not. ;^) (Anyhow, I got both your jokes, no need to explain.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the feedback. I certainly don't expect any links or supporting material. Just the opinion of an American English speaker is very useful.